# Ability to view my state using the browser dev tools

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a TypeScript file below named `dataStore.ts` and here is the content:

```
import { createStore, Store } from "redux";
import { StoreReducer} from "./reducer";
import { StoreData, StoreAction } from "./types";

export const dataStore: Store<StoreData, StoreAction> = createStore(StoreReducer);
```

I want to be able to add the code below so that I can view my state via the dev tools.

I've tried adding the line below my `createStore` but haven't had any luck.

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

Where do I add the line above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `composeWithDevTools` from the `redux-devtools-extension`.

So change your `dataStore.ts` to look like this:

```
import { createStore, Store } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension:;
import { StoreReducer} from "./reducer";
import { StoreData, StoreAction } from "./types";

export const dataStore: Store<StoreData, StoreAction> = createStore(StoreReducer, composeWithDevTools())
```

Don't forget to `yarn add redux-devtools-extension` OR `npm install redux-devtools-extension`.

After doing that, this line won't be necessary anymore:

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```